# MediaRSS feed problem

Tags: rss, media, feed, mediarss

I need to test an application that reads different mediaRSS feeds and work with the content. My problem is that I'm not able to find many of them. Could you help me with some links?

This is what I've found by now : http://feeds.nationalgeographic.com/ng/photography/photo-of-the-day/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flickr feeds use Media-RSS.

http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=22221172@N00&lang=en-us&format=rss_200

Dave

Answer (score 2):

Any Youtube channel you should be able to get a media rss feed, for example:  http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/garminblog/uploads

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/IronmanTriathlon/uploads?orderby=updated&alt=rss&client=ytapi-youtube-rss-redirect&v=2